# IAM policy and aws:RequestTag behaves differently as (to what I) expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:TagRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/*",
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "iam:TagRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/TeamCode": [
                        "aaaa"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I expect this policy to allow me to tag any role (from the first statement) except when I want to add a `TeamCode` tag that does not match 'aaaa'.

As illustration, if I want to add a 'CostCenter' tag to the role, I expect the `aws:RequestTag/TeamCode` key to be not present in the request context, which will cause the condition to be not met, and the deny to no not happen. This is not what happens when I test this with IAM Policy Simulator or actual roles. The deny block is activated every time (I get an explicit deny with roles, and the deny block is highlighted by Policy Sim).

What am I missing?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you get the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `aws:RequestTag/TeamCode` is not present, the following will be a **mismatch** (`false`):

```
                    "aws:RequestTag/TeamCode": [
                        "aaaa"
                    ]
```

But since you are using `Not` operator in `StringNotEquals`, you are **flipping** the condition to `true`, making it active.

Subsequently, your policy **only allows** for adding tag `TeamCode=aaaa` to a role. Every other tag will be denied due to mismatch.  The reason is that for this tag, the condition is `true` (there is a match), and the `Not` in your operator will flip it to `false` and `Deny` does not apply.

I don't know how to change your policy, as I don't understand what you want to achieve. I just explained you why you get the issue.

Comment: This explains the behaviour. I was misguided by a snippet on the 'JSON policy elements : Condition operators' page that claims: 
"If the key that you specify in a policy condition is not present in the request context, the values do not match."

I understood this to mean that the condition does not match regardless of any negation by operators in the condition. (I kinda still think that is what it says).